# Ruby On Rails 3, Pusher, Javascript, AJAX, Slow requests

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, pusher

I'm building a facebook chat app with a Ruby on Rails 3 backend and a HTML AJAX front-end.
For the sockets I use [Pusher](http://www.pusher.com). Everything works, but there's one drawback and that's performance.

A request to the Pusher API takes approximately 300ms, which is just too slow.

The code for triggering the Pusher API is this:

```
Pusher['presence-chat'].trigger!( 'message_added', { message: message, name: session[:user][:fullname], username: session[:user][:username] } )
```

The `Pusher` class is from a gem made by the pusher-developers.

I've recently posted on their forum, and waiting for the answer, but I'd like to know if someone here could point me in the right direction for speeding it up.

Just FYI:

The server the app is running on is in the Netherlands, and my guess is their server is not.

So the question is, what can be causing a simple `Net::HTTP` (because that's what the Pusher-gem is using) to be this slow?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've switched from my standard WEBrick server to Thin (= Evented Server).

And I updated my trigger method to an async trigger method:

```
Pusher['presence-chat'].trigger_async( 'message_added', { message: message, name: session[:user][:fullname], username: session[:user][:username] } )
```

And requests now take just 2 - 4 ms!

Thanks to Phil @ Pusher!

Answer (score 0):

Try pushing to the api in bacground using some background jobs

there are some swesome gems out the sidekiq, delaayed jobs, resque and more

also there are railscasts which will help you understand it easily

http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=background+job

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've recently used DelayedJob for another application, but what I've read in their docs is that the workers check the DB each several seconds, so I wonder if that would be faster than `300ms`? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

How about socket using node.js and RoR on front, you will get maximum performance with this configuration

you can refer this one 
http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2012/02/25/adding_real-time_to_rails_with_socket.IO_nodejs_and_backbonejs_with_demo/

Comment: I've came around this post, and I have to say it looks really great but I just couldn't figure out how to get it working.. I'm not really into servers and all, and the tutorial is not really detailed.. I'll give it another shot upcoming weekend, thanks for your answer though!